# How to route two components in the same page?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

How to route two components in the same page?

I can only route one side of it. Here is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7xt3m

Comment: If you want to have two components in the same page, build a wrapper component that has both ComponentA and ComponentB and route to that component

Comment: Can you please give me more details about what you want to do ?

Comment: @BELLIL I'm trying to have both left and right component show their main page  in the app component. Then if I click on page 2 of the Left side, the Right side would not be affected and stay on main page, so it's individual web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You had it almost!

Just replace your main routes configuration in `app-routing.module` with this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    children: [
      { path: "", component: LeftMainPageComponent },
      { path: "", component: RightMainPageComponent, outlet: "righty" }
    ]
  } 
  /* old config for reference
  { path: "main", component: LeftBoxComponent },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "main", pathMatch: "full" }
  */
];
```

Stackblitz based on you code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddc9en

Comment: This does work, but it doesn't show the right component after I click on page 2 on the left component.

Comment: That was not your original question. You asked for how to route two components in the same page.

Comment: Hi Kari, though it wasn't the original question can you give an idea on how to open the "left-page2" on the "right main page" on clicking the link "left-page2" on the left main page. So it doesn't open on a different page/screen.